# How to update and delete array of elements from child component and pass that to parent component in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**EDIT: I have created a codesandbox. Here is the link:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-rgb-ikq33?from-embed

I have a scenario in which I need to update the array in parent component from child component.

E.g, I am adding array contents from form, so if I have 7 items in child component ( that I am adding from child and passing them in parent component one by one from form ).

How I can edit/update single array row without mutating my original array?

The adding is working fine, I need to work on edit single item and update that in parent component ( that has all array elements from child ) but it seems like without mutation it cant be done.

**Parent component:**

```
handlePlansClick = (planData) => {
        this.setState(state => ({
            lead_plans: [...state.lead_plans, planData]
        }));
    }
```

**Child component declaration in Parent component:**

```
 <LeadPlans handlePlansClick={this.handlePlansClick} existing_lead_plans={this.state.lead_plans}
                                           must_contain_lead_plan={this.state.must_contain_lead_plan} lead_id={lead_id} updateMode={updateMode}/>
```

For adding to parent from child form I am using:

```
this.props.handlePlansClick({
                            id: Date.now(),
                            year: year,
                            probability: probability,
                            plan2: plan2,
                            plan3: plan3,
                            fee: fee,
                            addcosts: addcosts
                        }
                    );
```

**For updating:**

```
const {lead_id, lead_plans, year, probability, plan2, plan3, fee} = this.state;
            const new_lead = {
                id: lead_id,
                year,
                probability,
                plan2,
                plan3,
                fee,
            };
            const updated_lead_plans = lead_plans.map((lead) => lead.id === lead_id ? new_lead : lead);
            this.setState({
                lead_plans: updated_lead_plans,
                year: '',
                probability: '',
                plan2: '',
                plan3: '',
                fee: '',
                addcosts: '',
                newFieldsEditMode: false,
                LeadPlanSaveUpdateDialogOpen: false
            });
```

Now, its working as expected but problem is that its not updating my parent array in which I need to have updated array item. It updating all contents in child component only which I dont want to.

This below code needs fix as I want to remove existing item and update that updated one in parent array again that contains all array of elements:

```
const updated_lead_plans = lead_plans.map((lead) => lead.id === lead_id ? new_lead : lead);
            this.setState({
                lead_plans: updated_lead_plans,
                year: '',
                probability: '',
                plan2: '',
                plan3: '',
                fee: '',
                addcosts: '',
                newFieldsEditMode: false,
                LeadPlanSaveUpdateDialogOpen: false
            });
```

Similarly, for deletion I am using:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({lead_plans: prevState.lead_plans.filter(lead_offer_rec => lead_offer_rec !== lead_plan_row)}));
```

But it only working in child component as I want to remove item and update my parent array with that removed item as well.

How I can get that edit/update/delete from child and pass the updated array to parent again?

Comment: IIUC the function to update `lead_plans` currently resides in your child component and its `setState` call updates local state inside the child? If that is the case you can do the same as with `handlePlansClick`. Declare it in your parent, pass the function down to your child component and call it there. You can call it with arguments from your local child state, those values will arrive in your parent component

Comment: Yes I am working with the same case and its working without any problem, the only problem is I just want to update one element from child and pass that updated one to parent so that particular will get updated instead of any other element. Same goes for delete as well.

Comment: It could be just me, but it's not clear to me where your functions reside and where they are called with what arguments. If you really did declare it in the parent, then a `setState` inside that function body can't possibly update the child state. Can you prepare a codesandbox? You can simplify the data structure, as this doesn't really affect the problem at hand.

Comment: I have created a code sandbox. Here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-rgb-ikq33?from-embed

Answer (score 0):

In React the data flow should always be from the parent component to the child component and not vice versa.You can use a *'Global State management tool'* like `Redux` to pass data from one component to any other component(s) and update the root state object. Also `Redux` has a lot of boilerplate while implementing it so if the app is simple you can use `MobX`.

Comment: Could you give any example please? My module is fairly simple but I want to consume as much react way as i can! I am already using Redux.

Comment: you can just pass the new array to the Global state and a `boolean`.. so when you want to update the parent array, set the `boolean` to `true` and update it. Also could you post your code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)? It'll be easier to understand and answer it.

Comment: I have created a code sandbox. Here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-rgb-ikq33?from-embed

Comment: Basically what you want to do is pass the updated array from the `LeadPlan` to `LeadsSearchResults`. What you can do is set an `AllLeadArrays` key in the redux state. So after you add all the lead boxes in the `Modal`, when you click the *abort* button, ***dispatch an action*** in `LeadPlan` to save the new lead array to the redux state key - `AllLeadArrays`. After this in the `LeadsSearchResults` component use `connect` and `mapStateToProps` to get the data from the Redux-state and pass it as props to the component.

Comment: Also put the prop inside a Lifecycle method to re-render the component when the array is updated.